# Way to communicate between backend server ?

Tags: architecture, jms

I have to work on 3 distinct applications instead of a big one. 
My question is : "Can JMS be used to communicate between different servers (wildfly)" ?

This way we can add more servers for the second application if we see that take too longs to process. Here a simple exemple with 15 servers. 5 for the first app that take data and do something with them. 5 for the second app that calculate something and then that to the last application that format them and store them into a second DB.

If my second app takes too long, I would like to be able to add 3 servers on the fly and let them connect to the first JMS Q and the second JMS Q.

Maybe some other suggestion how to build something like that ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty standard messaging.

Might depend on your JMS server, but if you actually use queues, then each server should be able to consume individually and get the message to process.

The bigger issue is going to be the design of the applications.  They need to be stateless so that any message can be picked up by any server in any order and processed without regard to what else is happening.  [Of course, if there's a shared back-end data provider shared among all servers, then that could provide context.]

Another issue is going to be transactionality and recovery.  If a message is picked up by a server but, for whatever reason, the server can't process the message, do you have a transaction manager that allows you to roll back or do you have to put it back on a queue (either the originating one or a new one) yourself?  And then what happens if the message continues to fail for whatever reason, what does that mean (especially if there are additional messages that should be processed after the failed message).

So really need to consider the applications' architecture, but otherwise messaging is a sound solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Yes each server would be stateless and each message can be processed alone. For the transaction thing, I was thinking about a DLQ on the JMS Server. So I would be able to fix the applicaton and then transfer from the DLQ to the normal Q.